# How to run iPhone apps in widescreen mode on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, iphone-5

There is an application that has a design for a wide screen iPhone 5. I have the source code for the application.

Necessary to run the application on iPad with wide screen. I run it, but the iPad emulate standard screen of iPhone.

How do I do to show my iPhone application on iPad for wide screen?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode project target needs to have it's "Devices" setting set to "Universal" under the "iOS Application Target" section of the "Summary" tab. There are additional requirements once you have a Universal application, like size appropriate icons and launch images for the non-Retina and Retina iPads. [Apple's HIG for icons and launch image sizes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Furthermore, you need to then do whatever work is necessary for your user interface, be it with an iPad-specific Storyboard or xibs.